# Compiled ASP.NET App Doesn't Parse Classic ASP

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

If I shove our intranet app live and let it be compiled on the fly without compiling it beforehand it works fine.  If I publish the site by compiling it first using VS's built in publishing feature then every page works fine except for the classic ASP pages.

Anyone know why this would happen? We have classic ASP because there's thousands of pages, many migrated from old systems but we simply don't have time to convert them all (just before anyone starts saying "just convert them!").

Cheers!

Comment: What error messages do you get when trying to browse those classic ASP pages?

Comment: HTTP 500 error, so internal server error which is a generic message.  Runs on IIS6, it's a Windows Server 2000 box.

Answer (score 0):

ASP classic isn't enabled by default on newer versions of IIS.

[Here's how to enable it on IIS7.](https://web.archive.org/web/20210115210013/http://geekswithblogs.net/dlussier/archive/2007/08/12/114603.aspx)

Comment: No, it's on the exact same server.  It's running IIS6, and classic ASP works, just when the application isn't compiled ;)

Answer (score 0):

When you `publish` the app, VS only copies the files needed by the app and/or referred in the project file.

Maybe the ASP classic pages depends on a file that it's not included on the published site.

To test it, publish the site, and then compare the files in the server with your local copy to check for missing files. (You can use a tool like Beyond Compare)